# Having issues with my wordpress "widget" .. Trying to ping a minecraft server to see if it is online

Tags: php, ping, minecraft, wordpress

So i've been trying to write this widget for wordpress to check to see if my minecraft server that is hosted locally is online or not. I'm using hosting for my website and just having a slight problem with my code is all and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
<?php


define('PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));

add_action("widgets_init", array('sc_status', 'register'));
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('sc_status', 'activate'));
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array('sc_status', 'deactivate'));
class sc_status {
function activate(){
        $scdata = array( 'option1' => 'Default value' ,'option2' => 55);
        if ( ! get_option('sc_status')){
            add_option('sc_status' , $scdata);
        } else {
              update_option('sc_status' , $scdata);
        }
}
function deactivate(){
        delete_option('sc_status');
}
function control(){
        $scdata = get_option('sc_status');
    ?>
        <p><label>Title : <input name="widget_title" type="text" value="<?php echo $scdata['widget_title']; ?>" /></label></p>
        <p><label>IP : <input name="server_ip" type="text" value="<?php echo $scdata['server_ip']; ?>" /></label></p>
        <p><label>Port (25565) : <input name="server_port" size="5"  type="text" value="<?php echo $scdata['server_port']; ?>" /></label></p>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['server_ip'])){
        $scdata['widget_title'] = attribute_escape($_POST['widget_title']);
        $scdata['server_ip'] = attribute_escape($_POST['server_ip']);
        $scdata['server_port'] = attribute_escape($_POST['server_port']);
        update_option('sc_status', $scdata);
    }
}
function widget($args){



          wp_enqueue_style('sc', PLUGIN_URL.'/css/sc_button.css');

          $scdata = get_option('sc_status');
          $title = $scdata['widget_title'];
          $port = $scdata['server_port'];
          if(empty($port)) {
              $port = "25565";
          }

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if(!empty($title)) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }
        // Check Server Status
        $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
        if($fp = fsockopen($scdata['server_ip'],$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
           // It worked 
           echo '<div class="btn btn-success" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">online</div>';
        } else {
           // It didn't work 
           echo '<div class="btn btn-danger">offline</div>';
        } 
        fclose($fp);



        // End
        echo $args['after_widget'];
  }
  function register(){
        register_sidebar_widget('Servercraft Status', array('sc_status', 'widget'));
        register_widget_control('Servercraft Status', array('sc_status', 'control'));
  }
}
```

This works for the "most" part.. the problem it has is that the error is:

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to (don't want to post ip) (Connection timed out) on line 62

then it posts the "offline" div like it is supposed to.. followed by

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 69

so hopefully someone can either tell me what i'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

EDIT!
This is the code after I've done a couple fixes from the above portion. The problem i'm still having is that the server still is feeding back to the site that it is offline.. which it isn't at all.

```
<?php

define('PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));

add_action("widgets_init", array('sc_status', 'register'));
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array('sc_status', 'activate'));
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array('sc_status', 'deactivate'));
class sc_status {
function activate(){
        $scdata = array( 'option1' => 'Default value' ,'option2' => 55);
        if ( ! get_option('sc_status')){
            add_option('sc_status' , $scdata);
        } else {
              update_option('sc_status' , $scdata);
        }
}
function deactivate(){
        delete_option('sc_status');
}
function control(){
        $scdata = get_option('sc_status');
    ?>
        <p><label>Title : <input name="widget_title" type="text" value="<?php echo $scdata['widget_title']; ?>" /></label></p>
        <p><label>IP : <input name="server_ip" type="text" value="<?php echo $scdata['server_ip']; ?>" /></label></p>
        <p><label>Port (25565) : <input name="server_port" size="5"  type="text" value="<?php echo $scdata['server_port']; ?>" /></label></p>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['server_ip'])){
        $scdata['widget_title'] = attribute_escape($_POST['widget_title']);
        $scdata['server_ip'] = attribute_escape($_POST['server_ip']);
        $scdata['server_port'] = attribute_escape($_POST['server_port']);
        update_option('sc_status', $scdata);
    }
}
function widget($args){



          wp_enqueue_style('sc', PLUGIN_URL.'/css/sc_button.css');

          $scdata = get_option('sc_status');
          $title = $scdata['widget_title'];
          $port = $scdata['server_port'];
          if(empty($port)) {
              $port = "25565";
          }

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if(!empty($title)) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }


        // Check Server Status
        $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1;
        $fp = @fsockopen($scdata['server_ip'],$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds);
        echo "<span class='sc_status'> IP : ".$scdata['server_ip']."</span>";
        if($fp){                
            // It worked 
            echo '<div class="btn btn-success" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">online</div>';
            fclose($fp);
        } else {
            // It didn't work 
            echo '<div class="btn btn-danger">offline</div>';
        } 




        // End
        echo $args['after_widget'];
  }
  function register(){
        register_sidebar_widget('Servercraft Status', array('sc_status', 'widget'));
        register_widget_control('Servercraft Status', array('sc_status', 'control'));
  }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

very simple solution:

```
if($fp = @fsockopen($scdata['server_ip'],$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
 //it worked
 fclose($fp);
}
```

You just hide the error messages with the @. And only close the connection when it is open ( so move `fclose($fp);` to the "it worked" section).

Comment: Only problem is now.. The warning is gone.. but i'm still getting an offline message.

Comment: It isnt a port forwarding issue or the querying not being turned on.. I've been running my server without an issues.. its just now when I try to ping the server to see if its up or not.. it doesnt work. Ive checked to make sure the port is running.. just not sure how to get my php check to work is all.